# What does "spun off" in “Presuppose that the little body of dissenters suddenly spun off no less than a majority" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-meaning

"William F. Buckley—the movement’s Max Eastman, its most brilliant pamphleteer—predicted Goldwater’s landslide defeat. His candidacy, like the revolution of 1905, had come too soon, but it foretold the victory to come. At a Young Americans for Freedom convention, Buckley exhorted an audience of true-believing cadres to think beyond November: 'Presuppose that the fiery little body of dissenters, of which you are a shining meteor, suddenly spun off no less than a majority of all the American people, who suddenly overcome a generation’s entrenched lassitude, suddenly penetrated to the true meaning of freedom in society where the truth is occluded by the verbose mystification of thousands of scholars, tens of thousands of books, a million miles of newsprint.' Then Goldwater’s inevitable defeat would turn into 'the well planted seeds of hope, which will flower on a great November day in the future, if there is a future.'"
--the Atlantic

Comment: No meaning of _spun off_ that I am familiar with makes any sense there. What is the source?

Comment: It means: *Derive or produce from something else, especially a small part from a larger whole.* (Dictionary.com)

Comment: It would be very helpful to be aware of the context of this.  The word 'presuppose' looks odd to me in this context.  The term 'presuppose' usually occurs in relation to some other statement.  For example.  For example, the advice to "show your ticket at the barrier" presupposes that you have a ticket.  If you do not have a ticket, the the instruction is pointless.  You cannot ask someone to presuppose anything, just like that, without a context.  The normal word in your statement would be "assume" or "imagine".  The "spun off" has to mean change their support to your point of view.

Comment: The term "spin off" was popular maybe 20 years ago to describe a business that originally was a portion of a larger business but was cut loose.  I haven't heard it as much of late, though, as mergers have become more the norm.  And, of course, "spin off" is a common way to describe, say, a TV series that is developed based on another series, such as Frasier from Cheers, or Young Sheldon from Big Bang Theory.

Comment: The tone and content of this sentence scream _CRANK_ to me.

Comment: ... The tone and content of the passage certainly declare 'non-standard' (and thus C-V) to my ears.

Comment: Buckley was famous for his erudition (or orotundity, depending on your perspective), but I don't recall that he was especially famous for his command of colloquial idioms or the political jargon of the moment. It seems to me that in this case he was simply pursuing an extended metaphor of his own devising in which "all the American people" are imagined as some sort of mass of celestial dust within which a "fiery little body" of political activists (like a pod of shining meteors) travels; Buckley then proposes that this aggregation of meteors might suddenly spin off in its own direction, ...

Comment: ... rather like the swerving atoms of Lucretius, only with intentionality and moral clarity, and might draw with it through the force of its truth and intellectual gravity the majority of the foggy, dusty, aimless, and easily led American populace. It's really a rather silly metaphor to use, and the sense of "spin off" embedded in it probably never had much currency, but as a rhetorical flourish it does have the practical advantage of flattering its hearers by characterizing them as bright, shining objects coursing across the heavens.